# « the » edges - Lv 19:27

Tags: hebrew, leviticus

Why did all translators I could find translate Lv 19:27 with « the edges » and not with « edges » without the « the » ? Because I don’t see in the Hebrew text the ה for « the » about edges.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do English translators of Leviticus 19:27 include a "the" when there is no "ha"?

In [Vayikra (Leviticus) 19:27] we learn that "The" male children of Yisrael (בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֛ל) will distinguish themselves physically by not reshaping the "corner" or "edge" (פְּאַ֖ת) their head/beard. - However, we do not see a "Hei" to specifically identify where "The" corner / edge (פְּאַ֖ת) of the beard is located.

In Biblical Hebrew, the prefix "Ha" (הַ) is sometimes placed at the beginning of a word to specifically identify "The" noun or direct object in a sentence.  - Yet we notice In Leviticus 19:2 that "The children of Yisrael" (בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֛ל) does not include "The" Ha (הַ) to identify a specific child of the nation of Yisrael, but merely identifies any child of Yisrael. * In contrast, we see in Leviticus 19:22 "The" Ha prefix applied to Ha-Kohen (הַכֹּהֵ֜ן) for specifying "The" individual who should atone for sins.

Consider the use of The "Ha" (הַ) as a indicative prefix in [Bereishit (Genesis) 1:1] : In << the Beginning >> (Bereishit, בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית) does not have a "Ha" prefix before "reishit", because it does not specify the Beginning of << The Heavens >> (Ha-shamayim, הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם) from the Beginning of << The Earth >> (Ha-aretz, הָאָֽרֶץ). - - The "Ha" (הַ) prefix is used only to specify particular events, people, objects.

Comment: I’m sorry I haven’t really understand your answer.

Comment: In << the Beginning >> (Bereishit, בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית) does not have a "Ha" prefix before "reishit", because it does not specify the Beginning of <<The Heavens >> (Ha-shamayim, הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם) or the Beginning of << The Earth >> (Ha-aretz, הָאָֽרֶץ). - - The "Ha" (הַ) prefix is used only to specify particular events, people, objects.

Comment: Yes I see thanks, so literally in Lv 19:27 we shouldn’t have this « the » on the « the edges », correct ?

Comment: Another great explanation.  Thanks @ctaylorgraphics  +1

Comment: Gustav - you are correct. The literal translation of "Peat" (פְּאַ֥ת) is both "corner" and "edge" in Leviticus 19:27, since it does not include the "Ha" (הַ) prefix.

Comment: Thanks (תּוֹדָה), Dottard!